# Redirect entire domain with its corresponding URL and query string except one

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rule in my .htaccess that redirects an entire domain with its URL and query string to a new domain. However I want to exclude one URL from this. I want to still redirect that URL for strip out the query string from that. So for eg https://www.test1.com/search?type=content should be redirected to https://www.test.com/search  stripping out the query string but for the rest of the URL the below is fine.

```
  # Redirect users from test1.com to https://www.test.com
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)test1\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://www.test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you want to strip out query string on the `test` or `test1` domain?

Comment: @starkeen `test`. i have updated my question too.

Comment: Do `test1.com` and `test.com` point to the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
#redirect and discard querystring from /search?type=content
RewriteCond ℅{THE_REQUEST} /search/?\?type=content [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.test.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
# Redirect users from test1.com to https://www.test.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)test1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Great works. Thank you. Also I found this tool that helped me verified it too https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/